# Keep element vertically and horizontally centered in another element while allowing it to grow and be panned

Tags: css, scroll, transform

I am trying to keep an element horizontally and vertically centered while it grows inside a container, but while also allowing you to scroll and see the rest of the growing element.  I made a codepen that demonstrates my problem.

I am using `transformX` and `transformY` while also using `position:absolute` with left and right set to 50% as well.  The goal is that when you click the grow button, you should be able to scroll up, down left and right and see the whole image.  Currently something with the `transform` seems to be preventing you from getting back to the top and the far left of the image.  Any ideas?

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/erikdonohoo/pen/XmjrEw)

**EDIT**

I am using flexbox instead now, but still have the same problem.  Its visible in the updated CodePen.

Comment: To be honest, I don't see any of your explanation in that pen. Please clarify the exact issue. You may want to add you're using angular as well.

Comment: Oops.  Sorry.  I was in the middle of tweaking it.  If you wouldn't mind, take a look now.

Comment: Erik, Clicking on grow does nothing right now.

Comment: Are you sure?  I'm looking at it right now and it indeed does. At least in Chrome.

Comment: Works in Opera and IE too but not in FF.

Comment: Regardless of the firefox issue, I need to solve the missing scroll area issue

Comment: Using a transform won't influence page flow. I think you'd need to adapt the container size along with it.